# How to get the last insert id from a table with auto_increment that is not part of the last insert in the transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Is it possible to get the current id of an `auto_increment` primary key from a table that wasn't the table that had value inserted into in the last insert?

The situation I'm in looks like this:

1 - I insert an evaluation in the `Evaluation` table.

2 - I then insert in the `Evaluation_Details` table the results for each questions related to the evaluation using `last_insert_id()` and

3 - I finaly calculate all the statistics that I need for the evaluation based on the results of the questions and need to update the `Evaluation` table with it.

Now here is the problem. I need to get the id of the last insert in the `Evaluation` table but the `last_insert_id()` will now return the id for the last insert in the `Evaluatin_Details` table.

All is done in the same transaction and each table has `auto_increment` on its id.

I know that the query:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
```

can give me the value for the next id to be inserted but I don't think it is good practice to just query this and substract 1 to have the current id.

edit: I forgot to add that it IS possible that multiple users insert data at the same time. That's why I didn't use the `MAX(id) from table_name`.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name`?

Comment: Edited question, I forgot to mention that multiple inserts can be done by different users at the same time. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think you should add the tables' schema in your question. My first thought is that you should already have the id you need, otherwise how could you perform inserts in the `Evaluation_Details` table _related to the evaluation_

Comment: I don't think its possible to get previous insert ids. SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` ...` will not work for the same reason that `SELECT MAX(id)` doesn't. What is preventing you from getting the id immediately after the 1-st insert?

Comment: In the second step you describe, you insert multiple records into `Evaluation_Details` using the `last_insert_id()` from the `Evaluation` table insert. Since you have this id (I assume in some variable) why can't you use it to perform your last query? I really hope that you don't use `last_insert_id()` on each insert into `Evaluation_Details`...

Comment: @Cascader Thank you! It totally slipped my mind that I could use variables. I tested it and it works perfectly. Now I don't know if you could post it as an answer so I can accept it or post it myself or just close the question?

Comment: I'll just rephrase it and post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second step you describe, you insert multiple records into `Evaluation_Details` using the `last_insert_id()` from the `Evaluation` table insert. Since you have this id, you can store it in a variable and use it to perform your last query